# In Phonegap for android, Response text from webservice getting blank

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, windows-phone-7, cordova

I am calling webservice, when I sends request, in the response text it is not showing the data ie response text gets blank. Also status in android app showing 0 whereas in native it is showing 200.

Thanks,

Comment: Plese share some code or provide more specific details

Comment: function ShowDataFromWebService(){ var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = 'http://192.168.1.17:8080/WebService/Client_Math.php?Operation=Multiply&Value1=21&Value2=3';            
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (response) 
{if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {   
if (document.getElementById("Content").innerHTML != null) { 
document.getElementById("Content").innerHTML = xhr.responseText; }}}
xhr.open("GET", url,true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
xhr.send(null);}